# Time difference without considering times between 0am ~ 4am. MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

MySQL version 8.0

I want to calculate time difference between two datetime column.
And get rows where duration >= 12:00:00.

which I would normally do:

```
select id
     , start_time
     , end_time
     , timediff(end_time, start_time) as duration
  from table;
```

which I would get something like this:

```
    id    start_time               end_time              duration
0   1   2020-06-01 01:00:00   2020-06-01 14:00:00        13:00:00
1   2   2020-06-01 01:00:00   2020-06-01 18:00:00        17:00:00
2   3   2020-06-01 19:00:00   2020-06-02 10:00:00        15:00:00
3   4   2020-06-02 04:00:00   2020-06-02 16:00:00        12:00:00
```

For duration column I don't want times between 00:00:00 ~ 04:00:00 to be added towards the duration.
 So for the first row duration = 10:00:00 since 01:00:00~14:00:00 = 10:00:00, ignoring times between 00:00:00 ~ 04:00:00

same for second row we substract 3 hours from duration.

so my desired output would be:

```
    id    start_time               end_time              duration
0   1   2020-06-01 01:00:00   2020-06-01 14:00:00        10:00:00
1   2   2020-06-01 01:00:00   2020-06-01 18:00:00        14:00:00
2   3   2020-06-01 19:00:00   2020-06-02 10:00:00        11:00:00
3   4   2020-06-02 04:00:00   2020-06-02 16:00:00        12:00:00
```

There are lots of rows where times include minutes and seconds too.

Thanks in advance!

I've grabbed all rows where duration >= 12:00:00.

Then separated data into 4 regions depending on their start_time.

a_region = 00~04 
b_region = 04~12 
c_region = 12~16 
d_region = 16~24

For a_region I've subtracted 04:00:00 - start_time which is time we should compensate to duration in a_region.

compensation = 04:00:00 - start_time 
compensated_time = duration - compensation.

For b_region it needs no compensation if it has passed 00~04 it means it already passed duration = 12:00:00.

For c_region,
compensation = 16:00:00 - start_time 
compensated_time = duration - compensation

For d_region since we've grabbed duration >= 12:00:00

it will pass all of 00~04 therefore
compensated_time = duration - 04:00:00.

I solved it using Python but above is the logic I've used.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Are you sure you want to solve this using pure MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `greatest()`:

```
select id
     , start_time
     , end_time
     , timediff(
        greatest(, 
            end_time,
            date_format(end_time,  '%Y-%m-%d 04:00:00')
        ),
        greatest(
            start_time, 
            date_format(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d 04:00:00')
        ) 
    ) as duration
from table;
```

Comment: Hm... Not quite following with your answer.  Could you explain?